# Conditional constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to implement a constraint for the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE GLOBAL_LOCKS 
( 
  RESOURCE_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
  IS_EXCLUSIVE CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL 
)
```

as follows:

1. RESOURCE_NAME must be unique if IS_EXLUSIVE = 'Y'
2. RESOURCE_NAME can be duplicate if all of the records have IS_EXCLUSIVE = 'N'

---

```
--Example 1
INSERT INTO GLOBAL_LOCKS(RESOURCE_NAME, IS_EXCLUSIVE)
VALUES ('MY_RESOURCE', 'Y');
INSERT INTO GLOBAL_LOCKS(RESOURCE_NAME, IS_EXCLUSIVE)
VALUES ('MY_RESOURCE', 'N');
-- should fail

--Example 2
INSERT INTO GLOBAL_LOCKS(RESOURCE_NAME, IS_EXCLUSIVE)
VALUES ('MY_RESOURCE', 'N');
INSERT INTO GLOBAL_LOCKS(RESOURCE_NAME, IS_EXCLUSIVE)
VALUES ('MY_RESOURCE', 'N');
-- should work

--Example 3
INSERT INTO GLOBAL_LOCKS(RESOURCE_NAME, IS_EXCLUSIVE)
VALUES ('MY_RESOURCE', 'N');
INSERT INTO GLOBAL_LOCKS(RESOURCE_NAME, IS_EXCLUSIVE)
VALUES ('MY_RESOURCE', 'N');
INSERT INTO GLOBAL_LOCKS(RESOURCE_NAME, IS_EXCLUSIVE)
VALUES ('MY_RESOURCE', 'Y');
-- should fail
```

The idea is to maintain exclusive and shared locks in this table and rely on the constraint to enforce integrity. There can be only one exclusive lock for a given resource; but there can be multiple shared locks for a given resource.

This question is similar to https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=how-to-enforce-conditional-unique-on-multiple-columns but the solution does not work for this case because of the requirement #1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complicated because your requirement relies not on the value of any given row, but on the particular combination of rows. I think you will have to create a materialized view and a constraint on that mview.

```
create materialized view global_locks_validator
refresh force on commit as
select resource_name,
       max( case when is_exclusive = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end ) as max_is_exclusive,
       count(1) as resource_count
  from global_locks
 group by resource_name;

alter materialized view global_locks_validator add (
    constraint ck_validate check( max_is_exclusive = 0 or resource_count = 1 )
);
```

The drawback to this method is that the constraint is only validated when you issue the `commit`.

Comment: Thanks, @eaolson. This is a nice solution! I ended up going with a slightly different variant: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9539509200346184822.  I think it scales better since the mview uses a fast refresh.